# ¿Cómo saco un numero de una cadena de texto en C?

Tags: c, string

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que se le pide al usuario que introduzca lo que ha bebido (5 coca-cola, 3 cervezas) y el programa saque los numero del array y los sume, de tal manera que la solución sea (8 vasos de agua).
Da igual lo que se consuma, siempre van a ser 'x' vasos de agua.

yo he hecho esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{

char texto[100];
int n = 0,aux = 0,total = 0;

printf("Que ha bebido? ");
gets(texto);

n = strlen(texto);

for(int i = 0; i<= n - 1; i++)
    //         pongo n-1 para restarle el hueco nulo \0
{
    if(isdigit(texto[i]) == 1)
    {
        aux = aux * 10;
        aux += texto[i] - '\0';
    }
    else
    {
            total += total;
          // aux = 0;
    }


}
printf("%d vasos de agua",aux);

}
```

Si al programa le meto 3 fantas,2 cervezas y 5 coca-cola, me tendría que responder 10 vasos de agua, pero me responde 56538. Si alguien sabe hacerlo se lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola buenas, si pongo 5 fantas por ejemplo, me sale 56 vasos de agua y me debería salir 5 vasos de agua, gracias.

Comment: Ojo con las funciones que utilizas, `gets` tiene muchos bugs (de echo si lees el manual `man gets` te dice **Never use this function**) y [`strlen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html) puede ocasionar errores si la cadena de texto no tiene '\0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia el '\0' por '0' son dos caracteres diferentes. Y tampoco se porque va el aux = aux*10

Editado : la explicación es que '/0' significa null, o nulo, lo que significa a su vez que no le estás dando ningún valor a aux, y el espacio de memoria que literalmente vacío. Cuando la quieres volver a usar, como está vacío, en realidad el programa toma un valor aleatorio.

Usas '0',porque '0' también es un ASCII, y la distancia entre '0' y '6' o cualquier otro número, te da ese número porque están de corridos en el código ascii. El '0' es el 48, y '6' es 54, por eso restar 54- 48 te da 6.

Espero haber sido de ayuda :)